# Angular, change variable value in run block

Tags: angularjs

I have a run block, the code is

```
.run(['$rootScope', 'formlyConfig', 'appApiCheck', 'licenseExpDateValue', 
    ($rootScope, formlyConfig, appApiCheck, licenseExpDateValue) => {

    $rootScope.maskPlaceHolder = '';

    formlyConfig.setType({
        name: 'maskedInput',
        extends: 'input',
        template: '<input class="form-control" ng-model="model[options.key]" ng-required="{{licenseExpDateValue.required}}" ng-class="{\'has-error\':licenseExpDateValue.showError}"/>',
        defaultOptions: {
            ngModelAttrs: {
                mask: {
                    attribute: 'ui-mask'
                },
                maskPlaceholder: {
                    attribute: 'ui-mask-placeholder'
                }
            },
        templateOptions: {
          maskPlaceholder: $rootScope.maskPlaceholder
        }
      }
    })
}])
```

and later, I will fetch the data from server, and will change `$rootScope.maskPlaceholder`, but  `maskPlaceholder` in `templateOptions` is still the same.

how to update the `maskPlaceHolder` of `templateOptions`?

thanks

Comment: You could try using `angular.copy` instead of a direct assignment to preserve references however I feel like there's probably a better way. What is `someConfigData`? Where is it defined and in what scope does it exist?

Comment: @phil, thanks. I've updated my question. I am trying to use this plugin http://angular-formly.com/#/example/integrations/ui-mask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would  do this with a one-time watcher.  Something like

```
.service('UpdateConfig', [ '$rootScope', 'formlyConfig', function ($rootScope, formlyConfig) {
  var x = {
    updateConfig: function (maskPlaceHolder) {
      formlyConfig.setType({
        name: 'maskedInput',
        extends: 'input',
        template: '<input class="form-control" ng-model="model[options.key]" ng-required="{{licenseExpDateValue.required}}" ng-class="{\'has-error\':licenseExpDateValue.showError}"/>',
        defaultOptions: {
          ngModelAttrs: {
            mask: {
              attribute: 'ui-mask'
            },
            maskPlaceholder: {
                attribute: 'ui-mask-placeholder'
            }
          },
          templateOptions: {
            maskPlaceholder: maskPlaceholder
          }
        }});
    },
    watcher: $rootScope.$watch('maskPlaceHolder', function (value) {
        x.updateConfig(value);
        x.watcher();
    });
  };
  return x;
}])
.run(['$rootScope', 'UpdateConfig', 'appApiCheck', 'licenseExpDateValue',
    ($rootScope, UpdateConfig, appApiCheck, licenseExpDateValue) => {      
    UpdateConfig.update('');
});
```